# Room: Database calls retrieving null

Tags: android, recursion, android-room

I am attempting to call to my database from many different areas of my app, but I am having trouble saving and retrieving objects. When I inspect my data it looks like I am getting the cursor for the right columns, but it is ***always returning a null object*** even though it seems there is data in those columns.

[image: cursor columns with data]

I'm not sure what the issue is, but it may have to do with this recursive looking call into the database I found in the variable explorer (it continues this cascading for as far as I cared to explore). 
[image: recursive Dao]

To access my SQLite DB via Android Room I use a method call such as below from any relevant class (this gets called many times from various unique objects [should I be closing it?]):

```
@Entity(tableName = "cell")
public class LivingCell extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>{
    ....
    getCellsDB.getCell(uid);}

public CellsDBHandler getCellsDB(){
    if (cellsDBHandler == null)
        cellsDBHandler = CellsDBHandler.getAppDatabase(MainActivity.getContext(),uid);
        return cellsDBHandler;
}
```

Now I was under the impression that it wouldn't create a new instance of the database handler because this is what my CellsDBHandler looks like:

```
@Database(entities = {LivingCell.class})
public abstract class CellsDBHandler  extends RoomDatabase {
    private static CellsDBHandler INSTANCE;
    public abstract CellDao cellDao();
    public static CellsDBHandler getAppDatabase(Context context, String cityUid) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                        CellsDBHandler.class,
                                        DBPath).build();}
        return INSTANCE;
}

    public LivingCell getCell(String cellUid) {
        return cellDao().getCellByID(cellUid);}
}
```

And my CellDao

```
//ALL DAO CALLS ARE RETURNING NULL OBJECTS BUT HAVE POPULATED TABLES
@Dao 
public interface CellDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM cell")
    List<LivingCell> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT uid FROM cell")
    List<String> getAllUids();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cell WHERE uid LIKE (:cellUid)")
    LivingCell getCellByID(String cellUid);


    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insert(LivingCell cell);
...
```

Perhaps my call to MainActivity is the issue though... is this at all an acceptable way to find the application context?

```
private static MainActivity instance;
public static Context getContext(){
    return instance;
}
```

Incase it matters, all my UIDs are:

```
//form of: 1c21df2a-5b8f-4a56-ac5b-ed385ba8e4b8
uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: for context, you could return `this` (in your case `instance`) because Activity extends Context.

Comment: I caught that also, but unfortunately this did not resolve the null object being retrieved. I will update code.

Comment: The fundamental dilemma is that all calls to my CellDao() return a null object even though they contain data. Is my query bad?

Comment: shouldn't it be `LivingCell` in your query?

Comment: In this case my query is accepting (String cellUid) and returning LivingCell. This is desired, however every single request returns null even though I am able to discover the data through inspection of the cursor.

Comment: Not an expert, but `IN` is an operator for collections? Do you want to check for equality?

Comment: I do! My query should be comparing string literals and looking for a match. I am very new to SQL and Android, this is interesting consideration - but even 
LivingCell@Query(SELECT * FROM cell) returns null also.

Comment: `this.db.mAllowMainThreadQueries=true; getCellsDB().CellDao().getCount();` can be used to debug (should directly evaluate); it might return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

as the `cellUid` is a single String, not an Array or Collection, try the following

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cell WHERE uid LIKE :cellUid")
```

Comment: it reads `@Database(entities = {LivingCell.class})`- and when every query returns `NULL`, the table-name is questionable. strings might require delimiters. `LIKE \":cellUid\"`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite do it, as mentioned in the comment prior to this the problem persists when using **@Query("SELECT * FROM cell")**

Comment: @lostScriptie so what is the table name? (a cursor is still no guarantee for a window).

Comment: What the LivingCell.class looks like?

Comment: @MartinZeitler wondering why no exception gets thrown. I suspect the table name aswell, but couldn't figure out how camelCase should get translated into the query.

Comment: it's more than 500 lines including overloaded constructor methods and extends asynctask. Is there a specific part you're looking for? It makes various calls using the segments in the original post. Maybe I have a bad constructor and it can't recreate the objects...? Right now I am depending on it creating a blank object using LivingCell() which does exactly nothing. I then anticipated Room using this hollow-object to set the values of the public variables itself - is this not the case?

Comment: @sschrass, is SQL not supposed to have camel case? Should I just_be_using_this?

Comment: Want to see the `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: @MartinZeitler , the table is 
@Entity(tableName = "cell") LivingCell.class.

I demonstrate in the code in the post which segments of LivingCell are attempting to interact with Room. I have updated the code above to better reflect this declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177514/discussion-between-sschrass-and-lostscriptie).